# BibTeX - escape @ sign

Tags: bibtex

How can I escape an 'at sign' (`@`) is BibTeX?
I'm trying to cite a paper with "SETI@Home" in the title, and BibTeX complains.

I tried `\@` or `@@` but neither seem to work.

Comment: Do you have the title in braces (`title = {SETI@Home}`)? Try with quotes (`title = "SETI@Home"`)

Comment: You need double-braces:

`title = {{SETI@home}}`

Comment: What bibliography stype are you using? I don't get any error with `\bibliographystyle{plain}`; however the title would be lowercase without an additional pair of braces.

Comment: @PLK you could turn your comment into an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To protect such chars, you need to protect them TeX style, with braces, so either:

```
TITLE = {{SETI@home}}
```

or

```
TITLE = "{SETI@home}"
```

Comment: Double braces did not work, but the quotes did. Thanks.